Scientific / academic word for date-rape for accounts involving someone asleep
There are a handful of Greek myths that I want to address in a professional tone that involve a divinity sexually exploiting a sleeping maiden.
Sometimes these accounts are precipitated by the use of sleep inducing substances administered by the divinity himself, and so for the moment I've just used the term 'date-rape' but this seems too colloquial for my application.
In the epic poetry, the act is typically rendered as: "and Zeus stole the fruit of her maidenhood" or "untied her girdle" and other such flowery language. This is not scientific enough for my application. I can quote such lines, of course, but I will also want to analyze and provide commentary in formal prose.
So I would like to select a less charged of a word; perhaps a clinical or scientific word.
I would like to use a lofty-sounding, one-word academic term here:

Rapes often occur while the victim is awake, but ______ is the specific case of the act while the maiden is asleep.


The most honest single word is raped. With date rape, there is the initial romance and consent on that level. When the happy date morphs via coercion or roofies, there's the rape unadorned. Here, the nymph consented on no level.

That's true, I suppose I wanted something that specifically applied to her being asleep or unconscious; edited to clarify

The question's still ambiguous. Acquaintance rape is another term sometimes used for date rape, but it doesn't mean specifically raping someone who's asleep. I suggest you read the Wikipedia articles. Although rape is legal terminology and suitable for use in formal documents. Are you looking for a euphemism?

Would the woman view it as rape if a god chooses to give her the gift of visiting her body? Are you projecting a moral code  on a society with another code?

maiden? That's at least 16th century. Why would being asleep call for a new term here?

Unimaginable acts of rape : Between 2011 and 2020, Dominique P., a 71-year-old former employee with electricity provider EDF, allegedly incited more than 70 men to rape his wife while she lay unconscious at their home

The term is "sleep-facilitated sexual assault", as used by the research paper Sleep-Facilitated Sexual Assault: An Analysis of Case Data Featuring Female and Male Victims of Rape.
The US Drug Enforcement Administration and RAINN call it "drug-facilitated sexual assault" when substances are involved:

Drug-facilitated sexual assault occurs when alcohol or drugs are used to compromise an individual's ability to consent to sexual activity. — RAINN

Note that this includes cases where the victim isn't asleep too, since drugs can leave someone conscious and responsive but unable to think clearly.

What if they are drugged and asleep? sleep- and drug-facilitated sexual assault. I love that use of a hypen, though is the context ain't pretty. On another point, I do not understand why people don't upvote an obviously correct answer!
